# Deserialize Azure Blob stream to Json Object

Tags: c#, azure, serialization, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to deserialize the blob stream to JSON object using azure blob trigger. This trigger would be fired whenever I upload a video to blob storage. However, it is throwing this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path ''.

This is the code that I am using to deserialize:

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    myBlob.Position = 0; //resetting stream's position to 0
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(myBlob))
    {
        using(var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            BlobData blobData = serializer.Deserialize<BlobData>(jsonTextReader);
        }
    }

    public class BlobData
    {
        public string path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the actual contents of the blob?

Comment: A i mentioned earlier, the blob will contain a video and after upload a trigger will fire. As of now, i am using some sample videos.

Comment: When the blob is a video how could it be deserialized to a JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

> A i mentioned earlier, the blob will contain a video and after upload a trigger will fire. As of now, i am using some sample videos

As Gaurav Mantri commented that you could not deserialize a video to a JSON object. Per my understanding, if you want to retrieve the blob Uri after a video blob is uploaded and you would store the video blob url to some other data store. At this point, you could bind the `CloudBlockBlob` type for your `myBlob` parameter, and you could retrieve the blob url as follows:

**run.csx**

```html
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public static void Run(CloudBlockBlob myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
{   
    //blob has public read access permission
    var blobData = new BlobData() { path = myBlob.Uri.ToString() };

    //blob is private, generate a SAS token for this blob with the limited permission(s)
    var blobSasToken=myBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                 SharedAccessExpiryTime =DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(2),
                 Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
            }));
    var blobData = new BlobData() 
          { 
            path = $"{myBlob.Uri.ToString()}{blobSasToken}"
          };
    //TODO:
}
```

Moreover, you could follow [Create and use a SAS with Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2), [Azure Functions Blob storage bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob), [Get started with Azure Blob storage using .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) for more detailed code sample.